# VBA get DOM of HTML document

Tags: html, vba, dom

I want Excel to parse an HTML file for a specific table.

My current method is to get a DOM representation of the file and parse that. The problem is that the DOMDocument60 is throwing a parse error ("Invalid Syntax"). After some more research I found out that the DOMDocument60 object is only compatible with XML.

Are there any other options to get the DOM of an HTML file?

```
Sub myWebTest()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set File = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")

    File.setTimeout 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000
    File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx:80", False
    'This is IE 8 headers
    File.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
    File.Send

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set dom = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    'Dim dom As New DOMDocument60
    dom.LoadXML File.ResponseText
    MsgBox dom.ChildNodes.Length
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-time thing, you could try Excel's built-in import tool.  Click Data | Get External Data  (From Web).  You can give it the URL of the HTML page.

Comment: Good idea, but there are 50 pages of the same format that I want to update weekly

Comment: You can record a macro using the Get External Data and then use that as the starting point for your script.

Comment: It works to get a table, but I really want the DOM representation of the entire file. 

I already have a code basis that retrieves the HTML file from the web, I'm just trying to parse the response. Using the import-tool complicates things more than if I just wrote my own parser.

Comment: I see, sounds like you have to use MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 then.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488687/parse-html-content-in-vba

Comment: Nice. I was going over that post trying to get the doc object to work when I found out that apparently my problem goes away when I switch from DOMDocument60 to just DOMDocument. No idea why