# How can I extract website's info with hyperlinks using EXCEL VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a small list of websites (hyperlinks) in EXCEL from C2 to C90 right now and I need to find some informations like the website's name, postcode and email. It would speed up the process by script than by hand ;)

Actually, I've find this code for VBA to open every hyperlinks in once but it's still pretty long to find the information:

```
Sub OpenHyperLinks()
'Update 20141124
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

So, is there anyway for a script to open all the hyperlinks ($C2:$C90) and paste every "h1" tag from the HTML page to EXCEL ($A2:$A90) !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25493388/909742) answer: it should help you