# Extract JSON in Excel VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I want to parse stock quotes from the Robin Hood API via Excel VBA.

Say I want Amazon, which is `https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/?symbols=AMZN`.

Which produces:

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "ask_price":"1592.3900",
         "ask_size":100,
         "bid_price":"1591.0000",
         "bid_size":500,
         "last_trade_price":"1592.3900",
         "last_extended_hours_trade_price":"1592.0000",
         "previous_close":"1600.1400",
         "adjusted_previous_close":"1600.1400",
         "previous_close_date":"2018-05-07",
         "symbol":"AMZN",
         "trading_halted":false,
         "has_traded":true,
         "last_trade_price_source":"consolidated",
         "updated_at":"2018-05-08T23:58:44Z",
         "instrument":"https://api.robinhood.com/instruments/c0bb3aec-bd1e-471e-a4f0-ca011cbec711/"
      }
   ]
}
```

Using an example like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521809/issue-with-jsonconverter), I have installed [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) and turned on Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

My code:

```
Public Sub STOCKQUOTE()

 Dim http As Object
 Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

 Const sURL As String = "https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/?symbols=AMZN"
 http.Open "GET", sURL, False
 http.send

 Dim jsonResponse As Dictionary
 Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)

 Dim results As String
 Set results = jsonResponse("results")

 MsgBox results
End Sub
```

But this doesn't work, instead I get `Compiler Error: Object Required` for the line `Set results = jsonResponse("results")`.

If I add `Debug.Print http.responseText` I see the correct JSON, but any idea what I'm doing wrong?

VBA-JSON is installed correctly, because if I use [their example](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON), it works fine:

```
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456}}")
```

But if I try changing `Dictionary` to `Object`, I get `Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`.

Comment: `Results` is a string. You don't `Set` a string since it's not an Object. Also, more importantly, what you hoping would be written to that string since `Results` in your JSON has many attributes.

Comment: It's a stock quote, so `last_trade_price`. I can remove the entire `results` block and the original error remains if I try to Debug.Print `jsonResponse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json has an object called `results`. There could be, but isn't, multiple `result` objects. You have only one, so I think it's leading to confusion. Each `result` is going to get it's own entry in your `jsonResponse` dictionary. The ITEM in that dictionary will, itself, be a dictionary.

The best way to deal with iterating through the dictionary in a dictionary is to declare a new dictionary, I'm calling `att` for "Attributes" and then fill that dictionary with each iteration through the `jsonResponse` dictionary. It will only iterate once though as you only have one `result`:

```
Public Sub STOCKQUOTE()

    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    Const sURL As String = "https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/?symbols=AMZN"
    http.Open "GET", sURL, False
    http.send

    Dim jsonResponse As Dictionary
    Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)

    Dim att As Dictionary

    For Each att In jsonResponse("results")
     Debug.Print att("last_trade_price")
    Next att
End Sub
```

Alternatively, because you have only a single result, you could just refer to that result by it's index in the `jsonResponse` dictionary and then it's attribute you are after. This makes the code smaller, but if you ever get more than one result from your REST query it will be lost forever. No biggie though since you don't expect that to happen:

```
Public Sub STOCKQUOTE()

    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    Const sURL As String = "https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/?symbols=AMZN"
    http.Open "GET", sURL, False
    http.send

    Dim jsonResponse As Dictionary
    Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)

    MsgBox (jsonResponse("results")(1)("last_trade_price"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: hello, please, on line `Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)` it throws *run-time error 424 > Object required*, could you please help me with that? simple pointer will suffice, thanks!