# How to connect excel to microsoft's QnA Maker (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, azure-qna-maker

I receive excel files with questions on a regular basis (I have the answers from previous iterations. the questions are always similar) and I would like to automate the replies. I have created a Knowledge Base in Microsofts QnAMaker with all the question/answer pairs.

How can I call Microsofts QnAMaker to answer my questions from excel. I have been looking for a vba examples but I havent found anything so far.
I believe I need to make a HTTP request with authorization from excel using vba and then process the response.
Would someone have an idea on how I can make a request and process it?

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

These are the sample details QnAMaker provides to make the call:

```
 POST /knowledgebases/d02d1d7e-1bc0-461a-8074-37749cae41b9/generateAnswer
 Host: https://rfp1.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker
 Authorization: EndpointKey cec4b630-9e77-474f-8df4-e6430a5678c8
 Content-Type: application/json
 {"question":"<Your question>"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to do this. First is with VBA. Second is with Power Queries.

## VBA

#### Optional Setup

[image]

1. Add the Developer tab to the ribbon by going to File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Check Developer
2. Go to the Developer tab, then Insert > Button
3. Name the macro "GetReplies"
4. Click New

**Notes:**

- My QnAKB is based off of [this FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-bot-framework-faq?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), mostly.

#### VBA Setup

1. From the Developer tab, click the Visual Basic button (if it didn't open automatically)
2. Go to Tools > References and enable the following libraries:
   [image]
3. Import [this JSON library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) following [the installation instructions](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON#installation)
4. Copy/paste this:

VBA code:

```
Sub GetReplies()

    'User Settings
    Dim questionWorksheetName As String, questionsColumn As String, firstQuestionRow As String, kbHost As String, kbId As String, endpointKey As String

        questionWorksheetName = "Sheet1"
        questionsColumn = "A"
        firstQuestionRow = "2"

        kbHost = "https://**********.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker"
        kbId = "*******-****-****-****-**********"
        endpointKey = "*********-****-****-****-***********"

    'Non-User Settings
    Dim questionWorksheet As Worksheet
        Set questionWorksheet = Sheets(questionWorksheetName)
    Dim startCell As String
        startCell = questionsColumn & firstQuestionRow
    Dim questionsRange As Range
        Set questionsRange = questionWorksheet.Range(startCell, questionWorksheet.Range(startCell).End(xlDown))

    'Loop through all non-blank cells
    Dim answer As String
    For Each cell In questionsRange
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            answer = GetAnswer(cell.Value, kbHost, kbId, endpointKey)
            'Add answer to cell
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = answer
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function GetAnswer(question, kbHost, kbId, endpointKey) As String
    'HTTP Request Settings
    Dim qnaUrl As String
        qnaUrl = kbHost & "/knowledgebases/" & kbId & "/generateAnswer"
    Dim contentType As String
        contentType = "application/json"
    Dim data As String
        data = "{""question"":""" & question & """}"

    'Send Request
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    xmlhttp.Open "POST", qnaUrl, False
        xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", contentType
        xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "EndpointKey " & endpointKey
    xmlhttp.Send data

    'Convert response to JSON
    Dim json As Dictionary
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.ResponseText)

    Dim answer As Dictionary

    For Each answer In json("answers")
    'Return response
        GetAnswer = answer("answer")
    Next

End Function
```

5. Edit the "User Settings" at the top, appropriately

After running, I get:

[image]

## Power Queries

#### Create HTTP Connection Query

1. Data Tab > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query
2. Click Advanced Editor and copy paste

Code:

```
(Question as text) =>
let
    url = "https://***host****.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/****kbId******/generateAnswer",
    endpointKey = "****endpointKey*****",
    table = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Answers"]}[Content],
    row = Table.SelectRows(table, each ([Answer] = Question)),
    body = "{""question"":""" & Question & """}",
    Parsed_JSON = Json.Document(body),
    BuildQueryString = Uri.BuildQueryString(Parsed_JSON),
    headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json", #"Authorization"="EndpointKey " & endpointKey],
    content = Text.ToBinary(body),
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers = headers, Content = content])),
    answers = Source[answers],
    answers1 = answers{0},
    answer = answers1[answer]
in
    answer
```

3. Replace variables as necessary
4. Rename the Query to "GetAnswer"
5. Exit from Power Query, saving changes

#### Create the Table

1. Create a table with your questions

[image]

2. Select the table. Table Design Tab > Rename the table to Answers
3. With whole table selected, Data tab > From Table/Range
4. Add Column > Invoke Custom Function
5. Column name = Answers, Function query = GetAnswer, Question: ColumnName = Question
6. Ok. Ok/Exit/Save

You can then add a question to the table, go to the sheet where the Question/Answer table was created and click Refresh to get new answers.

Comment: Thank you very much! this worked perfect :) Would you know whether its possible to have the query return the confidence as well? Ideally, if an answer confidence is low, I would know which ones I need to examine in detail. Thank again!

Comment: You sure can. Towards the end of the code is the line `GetAnswer = answer("answer")`. If you change it to `GetAnswer = answer("score")` you get the confidence level/score instead of the actual answer. Personally, I'd use `GetAnswer = answer` and then in `GetReplies`, use `cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = answer("answer")` and `cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = answer("score")`. You may need to change the return type on `GetAnswer`. Let me know if you need help doing that.

Comment: Hihi, I have tried to adapt your solution to a word document as well but I am struggling.
I am trying to feed the GetAnswer method a single question (the text selected in word) but I get the following error at the line:   For Each answer In json("answers")
Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.
I think it has to do with the number of return objects?
I tried using the enclosed to solve but you are already implemented the suggested solution so I am a bit lost. Would you have any ideas?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244611/extract-json-in-excel-vba

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/issues/68). To fix: 1) Open Tools > References and move "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" above "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library". 2) In the VBA code, change "As Dictionary" to "As Scripting.Dictionary"

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I have implemented the fixes suggested and I believe it has been resolved, but the error moves to another section of the code. In the function, GetAnswer - xmlhttp send data line, I get an error stating: This method cannot be called after the send method has been called (it is the only 'send' method I see). Would you have any ideas?

Comment: @Freelancer If you can open a new StackOverflow question, include the code, and point me to it, I can help you out. I'm actually a support engineer for the Bot Framework, although we handle some QnAMaker stuff, so this is a little beyond the scope of my job. I'm willing to help out, though; just need to see your code to troubleshoot better.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I am grateful for your help :)  I have opened another question with the error code if you wouldnt mind taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55628303/6820783