# Trying to extract Wikipedia JSON data using Excel VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, web-scraping

I've got a column of terms in Excel, from which I need to extract the first sentence from Wikipedia. Wiki has an API for this and this provides me exactly what I need: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=&exintro=&exsentences=1&&titles=Stack%20Overflow under "extract".

I've installed VBA-JSON, my code is below but I'm not having any luck; I tried following examples here [Extract JSON in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244611/extract-json-in-excel-vba) but I received errors in regards to the 'results' object.

```
     Dim http As Object
     Dim term As String
     x = 2
     Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

     Do While Sheet2.Cells(x, 4) <> ""
     term = Sheet2.Cells(x, 4)

     Const sURL As String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=&exintro=&exsentences=1&&titles="
     http.Open "GET", sURL & term, False
     http.send

     Dim jsonResponse As Dictionary
     Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responsetext)
     Debug.Print http.responsetext

    Sheet2.Cells(x, 5).Value = http.responsetext
    x = x + 1
    Loop
```

The code above actually isn't running at all, so I don't know where to direct my focus. I've tried using "Debug.Print http.responseText" but it's not returning any result so I'm clearly doing something very wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: at least the URL string described in Post and the URL navigated in code is different. Code URL is only fetching  `{"batchcomplete":""}`. code URL missing title part, may be typo, please have a  look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheet2` is a [code name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) not necessarily the visible name so verify correct sheet first.

Add `option explicit` and declare all variables with their type

Then your url has an additional & at the end. Remove that and it works

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim http As Object, term As String, x As Long
    x = 2
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    Do While Sheet2.Cells(x, 4) <> ""
        term = Sheet2.Cells(x, 4)

        Const sURL As String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=&exintro=&exsentences=1&titles="
        http.Open "GET", sURL & term, False
        http.send

        Dim jsonResponse As Dictionary
        Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)
        Debug.Print http.responseText

        Sheet2.Cells(x, 5).Value = http.responseText
        x = x + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```