# How to extract href from html using VBA. HREF consist from multiple references

Tags: vba, extract, href

I am trying to extract `href` from salesforce, but the actual reference consists from multiple references. Element looks like this:

```
<a href="/*some random numbers and symbols*" data-seclke="Account"
data-seclkh="*another part of random numbers and letters*"
data-seclkp="*/more random numbers and letters etc.*">
```

I understand that this is how the link is built, but how to use it in the actual VBA code.

If anyone can at least point me to the right direction that would be great. Totally lost

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far? Also, what would the expected final link look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse HTML content in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488687/parse-html-content-in-vba)

Comment: Unless you provide more detailed information, this is a generic "How do I parse HTML in VBA?" question, and there are many posts here and elsewhere that show solutions for this. Look around, pick one, try how far you get.